# Apache sandbox and file uploads on VPS

Tags: php, linux, apache, security

Following this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7497357/1974224), the user under which `Apache` runs should not be allowed to write to any files. Which is very OK from a security perspective, however how can a `PHP` web application that allows file uploads can work with such a setup?

A virtualization tool, like `linux-vserver`, or `OpenVZ` (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145540/best-way-to-sandbox-apache-on-linux)) would be one alternative, however I'm not sure about the performance hit, as my `linux` box is already running inside a `virtual machine`.

Another approach that crossed my mind would be to use a process that runs under a user with write privileges on the `uploads` folder, and have my `PHP` scripts communicate with it via `IPC`.

I'd incline towards the second solution, however before I start developing that app and hit my head against the wall a few times before I make it work right and without crashes, I'd like to know if there are simpler solutions to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the user or group the php code is executed by write access to a single uploads folder, and disable php execution for that directory.

If you're using mod_php, it will be the Apache user.

If you're using php-fpm it may *default* to the Apache user but it can certainly be changed (even per-pool, if you have multiple pools for different apps/sites)